# Best way to plot marks on a line in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

This question is quite basic, but I am looking for the best way to do this.
For a plotted line in matlab, how can a few points on the line be marked. I know it is possible to plot directly using marks. But, in case the line has been plotted and the marks are just to differentiate the plots. Instead of selecting a few points and plotting the second time. An example is shown in this figure below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right after creating the initial plot you can use the command 'hold on' to keep that plot 'live' and then replot the points as markers. For example:

```
x=1:10;
y=2*x+4;
plot(x,y)
hold on
plot(x,y,'+')
```

You can use '*', '.' or any other marker instead of '+'.

If you want the markers to be evenly spaced (and your data is not ,originally) you may create an evenly spaced x vector and then, assuming your plot is not too extreme, interpolate the y values and add just the points. For example:

```
x=[1,1.5,2,2.3,3,4,4.8,5,6.1,6,7,8,9,10];
y=2*x.^2+4;
plot(x,y)
hold on
x_lin=linspace(min(x),max(x),20);
y_lin=interp1(x,y,x_lin,'linear');
plot(x_lin,y_lin,'+')
hold off
```

With the following result:
[image: evenly spaced markers]
If 'linear' doesn't give a good enough result you can try other interpolation methods like 'cubic', 'spline'...

Comment: Thanks @ Omer! Using a '+' sign fits, but it doesn't give an even spacing as shown on the graph. I want it to plot the sign on evenly spaced points not all the points.

Comment: ToIf the relation between x and y is not too 'extreme' you may

Comment: The last comment was accidental. I added to my response to answer what I now understand as your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to "add" the marked points in a second moment (**but I don't think you will have some advantage**), consider to

A) use two plot instructions, separating the array of points "to be marked" using

```
C = setdiff(A,B)
```

alternatively

B) plot every point in a for cycle with counter i under a condition

```
%not tested solution    
c1 = '.r' %red point, if they are near they seems a line
c2 = '*b' %blue marker
if (marker_condition == true)
   plot(x(i), y(i), c2)
else
   plot(x(i), y(i), c1)
end
```